# Xamarin Android, Java Bindings Library and IJavaPeerable Implementation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a Bindings Library as detailed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/javaintegration-aarbinding/ for a .aar file.

This exposes a method

```
GetBarCode (global::Com.Scandecode.Inf.IScanInterfaceOnScanListener scanListener)
```

IScanInterfaceOnScanListener inherits IJavaObject, IJavaPeerable.

How do I implement the inherited methods from IJavaPeerable so I can call this method?

```
void SetJniIdentityHashCode(int value)
void SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference reference)
void SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates value
void UnregisterFromRuntime()
void DisposeUnlessReferenced()
void Disposed()
void Finalized()
```

OR
Is there a problem with my bindings library? This is the example Java code given:

```
       scanDecode.getBarCode(new ScanInterface.OnScanListener() {
            @Override
            public void getBarcode(String data) {
                scancount+=1;
                tvcound.setText(getString(R.string.scan_time)+scancount+"");
                mReception.append(data+"\n");
            }

            @Override
            public void getBarcodeByte(byte[] bytes) {
                //返回原始解码数据
//                scancount+=1;
//                tvcound.setText(getString(R.string.scan_time)+scancount+"");
//                mReception.append(DataConversionUtils.byteArrayToString(bytes) +"\n");
            }
        });
```

ScanInterface.OnScanListener does not appear to be generated by the Bindings library.

Background: This is for integration with a hardware barcode scanner on a Newland SD100 tablet.

Edit:
Seems similar to implementing IEventListener, will do some more research

Comment: Hi, you could submit this in Github [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/new/choose), there is a topic about **Issues trying to bind an Android library using an Android Bindings project.**

Comment: Not an answer as such to the question, but in this case I found an alternative way of integrating with the scanner using BroadcastReceivers

Comment: That's great. You could update it as a solution in answer, it will also help others who have  the same pronlems with a alternative ways to solve it.